# Angular 2 custom validator how to set control.valid true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

I have such custom validator:

```
static isEmail(control:Control):{[key:string]:boolean} {
  let emailRegExp = new RegExp("^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{'?]+(.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(.[-a-z0-9_]+)*.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$", 'i');
  if (control.value.match(emailRegExp)) {
    return {isEmail: true};
  }
  return {isEmail: false};
}
```

Use it in component:

```
loginForm:ControlGroup;

constructor(private _router:Router,
          private _loginService:LoginService,
          private _formBuilder:FormBuilder) {
this.loginForm = _formBuilder.group({
  email: ['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(8),
    FormValidationService.isEmail
  ])],
  password: ['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(8),
    Validators.maxLength(30),
    FormValidationService.isPassword
  ])]
 });
}
```

And template:

```
 <form id="login-form" role="form" [ngFormModel]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onLoginSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="loginFormEmail">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="loginFormEmail" class="form-control"
             ngControl="email" #email="ngForm">
      <div *ngIf="email.dirty && !email.valid">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" [hidden]="!email.errors.minlength">
          Email field must have more then 8 characters
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" [hidden]="email.errors.isEmail">
          Email not valid
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="loginFormPassword">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="loginFormPassword" class="form-control"
             ngControl="password" #password="ngForm">
      <div *ngIf="password.dirty && !password.valid">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" [hidden]="!password.errors.minlength">
          Password field must have more then 8 characters
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" [hidden]="!password.errors.maxlength">
          Password field must have no more then 30 characters
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" [hidden]="password.errors.isPassword">
          Password must meet the following rules:
          <ul>
            <li>At least one upper case english letter</li>
            <li>At least one lower case english letter</li>
            <li>At least one digit</li>
            <li>At least one special character</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>If you forgot your password you can <a (click)="toForgot()">reset it</a>.</p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Login</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

If you look in screenshot you can see that custom validator return my value. But regardless of its value control.valid always false, so form invalid to.

[image]

I try to set `control.valid = true`, but this field have only getter.

Comment: I found in docs method setErrors()
Anyone else used it?

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/AbstractControl-class.html

Answer (score 1):

I found answer. When control value is valid you must return null in your custom validator:

```
static isPassword(control:Control):{[key:string]:boolean} {
  let passwordRegExp = new RegExp("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$");
  if (control.value.match(passwordRegExp)) {
    return null;
  }
  return {isPassword: false};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `ngControlGroup` to wrapping elements otherwise the form won't track the containing input elements

```
<div class="form-group" ngControlGroup="someName">
```

See also [NgControlGroup](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgControlGroup-directive.html)

Answer (score 0):

You mixed inline form definition with ngForm and definition in JS code using the FormBuilder class.

You should refactor your input definitions this way to use the ngFormControl directive:

```
<input [ngFomControl]="loginForm.controls.password" .../>
```

Comment: I think you in right way. But now it not work for me.

https://postimg.org/image/h1lfaztt9/

https://postimg.org/image/hgyv67271/

Comment: I think that you forgot to update your ngIfs ("loginForm.controls.password.dirty && !login.controls.password.valid" for example) and use the Elvis operator in your expressions for hidden: "loginForm.controls.password.errors?.isPassword" for example.